# ResourceManager - how to find a required base name for an embedded resource file?

Tags: c#, .net, resources, resourcemanager

I have a library loading the resources from an external file as follows:

```
ResourceManager rm = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager(stringsFileName, ResourcesDir, null)
```

Now I'd like to change the loading from external file to an embedded resource. I've attached a ".resources" file to the project, and changed its build action to "Embedded Resource". Loading it as follows:

```
   System.Resources.ResourceManager myManager = new
                   System.Resources.ResourceManager(resName,
                   myAssembly);
```

This compiles fine. However, at runtime the application reports the following error:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure "Strings.3.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly "TestApp.Resources" at compile time,
>   or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed.

This happens regardless of the name I pass, so my question is how to find the correct base name for the resource file I just embedded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the resource name is fully qualified, so it would be {assemblyNameSpace}.Strings.3.resources.

You can confirm this by using a disassembler/decompiler like dotPeek: http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/